# SQL groupby having count distinct

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a postgres database that contains a table with IP, User, and time fields. I need a query to give me the complete set of all IPs that have only a single user active on them over a defined time period (i.e. I need to filter out IPs with multiple or no users, and should only have one row per IP). The user field contains some null values, that I can filter out. I'm using Pandas' read_sql() method to get a dataframe directly.

I can get the full dataframe of data from the defined time period easily with:

```
SELECT ip, user FROM table WHERE user IS NOT NULL AND time >= start AND time <= end
```

I can then take this data and wrangle the information I need out of it easily using pandas with groupby and filter operations. However, I would like to be able to get what I need using a single SQL query. Unfortunately, my SQL chops ain't too hot. My first attempt below isn't great; the dataframe I end up with isn't the same as when I create the dataframe manually using the original query above and some pandas wrangling.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip, user FROM table WHERE user IS NOT NULL AND ip IN (SELECT ip FROM table WHERE user IS NOT NULL AND time >= start AND time <= end GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user) = 1)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Thanks.

*edit*: I neglected to mention that there are multiple entries for each user/ip combination. The source is network authentication traffic, and users authenticate on IPs very frequently.

Sample table head:

```
---------------------------------
ip         | user    | time
---------------------------------
172.18.0.0 | jbloggs | 1531987000
172.18.0.0 | jbloggs | 1531987100
172.18.0.1 | jsmith  | 1531987200
172.18.0.1 | jbloggs | 1531987300
172.18.0.2 | odin    | 1531987400
```

If I were to query this example table for the time range 1531987000 to 1531987400 I would like the following output:

```
---------------------
ip         | user 
--------------------
172.18.0.0 | jbloggs
172.18.0.2 | odin
```

Comment: This probably doesn't have anything to do with pandas, if you're trying to avoid using the library.  Either way, some sample data would be great, or at least the post-processing you do with pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a query that gets me what I want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip, user 
FROM table
WHERE user IS NOT NULL AND time >= start AND time <= end AND ip IN 
(SELECT ip FROM table 
WHERE user IS NOT NULL AND time >= start AND time <= end 
GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user) = 1)
```

Explanation:

The inner select gets me all IPs that have only one user across the specified time range. I then need to select the distinct ip/user pairs from the main table where the IPs are in the nested select.

It seems messy that I have to  do the same filtering (of time range and non-null user fields) twice though, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
SELECT ip
FROM table
WHERE user IS NOT NULL AND time >= start AND time <= end
GROUP BY ip
HAVING COUNT(ip) = 1
```

Explanation:
`SELECT ip FROM table WHERE user IS NOT NULL AND time >= start AND time <= end` - filtering out the nulls and time periods

`...GROUP BY ip HAVING COUNT(ip) = 1` - If an ip has multiple users, the count(no. of rows with that ip) would be greater > 1.

Comment: I should have been clearer in my original question, but there are multiple rows for each ip/user combination (it's network authentication traffic, users authenticate multiple times a day). I think need count(distinct user) = 1 rather than count(ip) = 1.

Answer (score 0):

If by "single user" you mean that there could be multiple rows with only one user, then:

```
SELECT ip
FROM table
WHERE user IS NOT NULL AND time >= start AND time <= end
GROUP BY ip
HAVING MIN(user) = MAX(user) AND COUNT(user) = COUNT(*);
```